# How to specify a replacement string with a newline in it?

Tags: regex, find-and-replace

I am using [Source Insight](http://www.sourceinsight.com/).

I am trying to replace the string
`Tmem::Set` with the following string that includes a newline in it.

```
//here
memset
```

I set the replacement string to be the regex `[//here \n memset]`
but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. what are you asking? there is no question.

Comment: I am asking how to replace with newline in source insight using regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to perform this action. Tested in Debian.

```
sed -i '/Tmem::Set/c\//here\nmemset' [filename]
```

Enjoy